# Building a constant current circuit

Tags: amplifier, pwm, dc-dc-converter, constant-current

The constant current output should be able to be set from 0.2 mA to 20 mA with a load of 3500 ohms ±50% from a 5V battery source and a PWM signal set by a microprocessor.  Do I need a transformer or can this be done with an opamp LM358 and a NPN transistor 2N2222? By varying the duty cycle?  What would the circuit look like?

Comment: That's two orders of magnitude change. So you will need to specify whether you need tiny linear steps the entire range or can accept fine-grain near the lower end and larger-grain nearer the upper end or whatever. Not enough specified for two orders dynamic range. Also, you will need over 100 V compliance to hit 20 mA at 3500*1.5 Ohms able to deliver 2 W into the load, so around 1/2 amp from the 5 V "battery" (don't know of any batteries at 5 V, myself, just DC supplies.) Problem 1: Boost 5 V DC to ~110 VDC. (Assuming you don't need bipolar, 2-quadrant current direction into load.)

Comment: Fine grain near the low end and larger as it goes up.  The 5v comes off of USB to go off of a bat management chip 3.7v lion cell.  Very low duty cycle approx. 10mSec on per minute.  Yes on Problem 1, but the max will be rare.  Usual closer to 2mA, but will vary (not in the 10mSec).  Bipolar achieved by switching electrodes.

Comment: A small signal BJT will provide a temperature-impacted logarithmic voltage output you can use to measure the current. At room temp that will be about 60 mV per decide of current. So over two decades you would get a linear 120 mV change that could be used for comparison. That can be multiplied (gain) so that the range is more convenient to use. But it gets you fine grained to larger grained control, that way. And over 2 orders, that may help some. You could just boost a voltage and then store it on a cap for use over 10 ms. Lots of ways to go. But your undisclosed situation so can't guess.

Comment: @periblepsis Peripheral electrical stimulator - the cap will not discharge at the same rate under a varying load so I need a control circuit, not sure how best to do the feedback or what this looks like

Answer (score 1):

The best circuit for a fine-tunable constant current source would be a **Howland Current Pump**. There are various versions of it, and the version I prefer using in particular is the following:

[image]
Image Source: [Here](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Howland-current-source-with-buffered-feedback_fig2_338872742)

In this circuit, the maximum current is limited by either (a) the resistor Rs, or (b) the maximum output current of the op amp you choose.

You can buffer the output of the op amp to provide additional current control, but make sure to include it in the feedback path.

This circuit will output a current relative to the resistor Rs and the input voltage.

For the input voltage, what you will want to do is convert your PWM into a constant voltage with a low pass filter. I believe that was done in the paper I sourced the above circuit image from.

---

- Here is an [application note by TI](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sboa441/sboa441.pdf?ts=1701216514570&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.bing.com%252F) on the improved version of a Howland current pump.
- An additional application note by TI on the original Howland current
  pump pdf can be [found here](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snoa474a/snoa474a.pdf).
- A tutorial for the Howland current
  pump can be [found here](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/the-howland-current-pump/)
- yet another TI application note: [Here](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sboa437a/sboa437a.pdf?ts=1701217104466&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Ftool%252FCIRCUIT060044)

I hope that provides plenty of information to run off of!